# Right way to use css pseudo selector?

Tags: html, css

I have been playing with pseudo selectors and trying to figure stuff out.

This is the general look of the element I am trying to work on:

```
<div class=simpleGallery>
     <a href="...">
         <img data-attachment-id="some_number" ........>
     </a>
</div>
```

I am trying to get text to show on a picture with a specific attribute (data-attachment-id for example). I managed to get it by searching for a href that ends in a unique way. Like this...

```
.simpleGallery a[href$="GP120094-1.jpg"]:before{
content:'Hokus Pokus';
position:absolute;
bottom:25%;
opacity:0;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
color:#fff;
box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-transition: all 1.2s ease;
-webkit-transition: all 1.2s ease;
transition: all 1.2s ease;
}
```

And then I get the text to show with:

```
.simpleGallery a:hover:before{
opacity:1;
z-index:1;
-moz-transform: scale(1.1);
-webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

It all works, but I was wondering why it won't work with something like this:

```
.simpleGallery a:before img[data-attachment-id="some_number"]
```

How would it be done by the image data-attachment-id instead of href in the `<a>` tag?
And why?
Is it because the :before can only go after the last element I am looking for?

Comment: Please note that the actual problem with this situation here is that it's impossible to add texts to an img, since an img is a _replaced element_, and any content in it can not be shown. So... you cannot use `::before` or `::after` on the img itself (it won't work) and you have to make do with showing extra content using `::before` or `::after` on the elements surrounding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.simpleGallery a:before img[data-attachment-id="some_number"]`

Is saying:

1.) find an element with the class "simpleGallery"

2.) find a descendant anchor tag

3.) target that element's `:before` pseudo element

4.) find a descendant img tag of that pseudo element who's data-attachment-id is equal to "some_number"

The problem here is that pseudo elements are not real elements on the dom (hence pseudo) so they don't have children, siblings, decedents, etc. so your selector is invalid.

> How would it be done by the image data-attachment-id instead of href
>   in the tag?

Exactly how you have it: `img[data-attachment-id="some_number"]`